# Как создать параграфы(тэг P) из текста с переносами строк?

Tags: javascript, html

Есть текст с переносами строк. 
Как правильно преобразовать это в набор параграфов p?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var text = `Есть текст с переносами строк.
Как правильно преобразовать это
в набор параграфов p?`;

var df = document.createDocumentFragment();

for (var line of text.split('\n')) {
  var p = document.createElement('p');
  p.textContent = line;
  df.appendChild(p);
}

document.querySelector('main').appendChild(df);
```

```css
main { background: silver; overflow: hidden; }
```

```html
<main><h1>Заголовок</h1></main>
```

Comment: Qwertiy,  я правильно понял,  что помощью document.createDocumentFragment();  создаешь определенный фрагмент страницы с разным уровнем вложенности и  потом можно его засунуть куда угодно, когда надо?  P.S. Кстати поздравляю с присвоением  ромба...

Comment: @Air, фрагмент - это нечто типа dom-элемента, только при вставке куда-либо он сам растворится и вставится его содержимое.

Comment: понятно, благодарю

Answer (score 1):

возможно имелось в виду тэг **pre**?

```html
<body>
<pre>
    Есть текст с переносами строк. 
    Как правильно преобразовать это в набор параграфов p?
    Есть текст с переносами строк.
    Как правильно преобразовать это в набор параграфов p? 
</pre>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Подозреваю, что на самом деле тебе нужны не абзацы, а `white-space: pre-wrap`:

```css
main {
  white-space: pre-wrap;
}
```

```html
<main>Есть текст с переносами строк.
Как правильно преобразовать это
в набор параграфов p?
Есть текст с переносами строк. Как правильно преобразовать это в набор параграфов p? Есть текст с переносами строк. Как правильно преобразовать это в набор параграфов p? Есть текст с переносами строк. Как правильно преобразовать это в набор параграфов p?</main>
```

Comment: Нет, нужно не средствами css сделать.